# Java EE7 - Bean discovery none

Tags: jakarta-ee, javabeans, cdi, java-ee-7

I understand why someone would want to use bean discovery all or annotated but I cannot imagine when you'd need to use the discovery-none property. Can anyone provide me with a good scenario where you'd use bean discovery none? Thanks

Comment: A use case here: https://developer.jboss.org/people/mkouba/blog/2013/09/20/bean-archives-in-cdi-11

Answer (score 2):

If you're using spring, and you dont' want your app server to pick up on your archive, you can use this.

If you have an archive where there are no beans in it (e.g. a JAR in a WAR file that maybe just has models in it).